# ERROR: Redirects to login in every controller action in Croogo, cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, croogo

good afternoon,

I'm currently working with croogno version 2.0.0.dev.2 and I was trying to add my own controller (not plugin) named itemscontroller which displays items. I've encountered 2 problems:
1. Everytime I try to paginate my items it always redirect me to the login. after I login, I get redirected to the page I was heading to, but then again if I try any other links it asks to log in. Where could be the problem and how can it be solved?

1. In my pagination, the button links contains extra urls, which are unnecessery. for example, the link becomes `http://localhost/myapp/items/page:2/page:2?%2Fitems=` instead of just `http://localhost/myapp/items/page:2/`.

Can anyone please help me with these problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to try creating the MVC files via the bake tool and compare the difference with your hand-written files.

For an example:

```
$ Console/cake bake model Item

Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.0-dev Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : croogo-app
Path: /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------
You have more than one set of templates installed.
Please choose the template set you wish to use:
---------------------------------------------------------------
1. croogo
2. default
Which bake theme would you like to use? (1/2) 
[1] > 1

Baking model class for Item...

Creating file /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Model/Item.php
Wrote `/home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Model/Item.php`

Baking test fixture for Item...

Creating file /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Test/Fixture/ItemFixture.php
Wrote `/home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Test/Fixture/ItemFixture.php`
Bake is detecting possible fixtures...

Baking test case for Item Model ...

Creating file /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Test/Case/Model/ItemTest.php
Wrote `/home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Test/Case/Model/ItemTest.php`

$ Console/cake bake controller Items --public

Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.0-dev Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : croogo-app
Path: /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Baking basic crud methods for Items
---------------------------------------------------------------
You have more than one set of templates installed.
Please choose the template set you wish to use:
---------------------------------------------------------------
1. croogo
2. default
Which bake theme would you like to use? (1/2) 
[1] > 1

Baking controller class for Items...

Creating file /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Controller/ItemsController.php
Wrote `/home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Controller/ItemsController.php`
Bake is detecting possible fixtures...

Baking test case for Items Controller ...

Creating file /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Test/Case/Controller/ItemsControllerTest.php
Wrote `/home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/Test/Case/Controller/ItemsControllerTest.php`
$ Console/cake bake view Items 

Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.0-dev Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : croogo-app
Path: /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------
You have more than one set of templates installed.
Please choose the template set you wish to use:
---------------------------------------------------------------
1. croogo
2. default
Which bake theme would you like to use? (1/2) 
[1] > 2

Baking `index` view file...

Creating file /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/View/Items/index.ctp
Wrote `/home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/View/Items/index.ctp`

Baking `view` view file...

Creating file /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/View/Items/view.ctp
Wrote `/home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/View/Items/view.ctp`

Baking `add` view file...

Creating file /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/View/Items/add.ctp
Wrote `/home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/View/Items/add.ctp`

Baking `edit` view file...

Creating file /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/View/Items/edit.ctp
Wrote `/home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo-app/View/Items/edit.ctp`
```

*Note that when baking views, I chose the default template.*

Using these generated files, I seem to have no problem adding new items and paginating the records.